# Create Bipartite Query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

[EDITED]

I have a database that represents GitHub data, which consists of User nodes and Repo nodes, with a directed relation from Users to Repo's called [:CONTRIBUTED].

I am trying to get tabular data to build a bipartite graph in R, but can't figure out how to do so.

```
MATCH (n:User{name:'mattt'})-[*]-(g)
RETURN g LIMIT 100
```

This gives me a graph that I want, but am unsure how to format the output to be tabular.

I want to have `mattt` in the results, and all the users/repos that are 1-2 degrees away. And I also want to be able to recreate the subgraph from the results, so it needs to contain info about the relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

This query uses [aggregation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html) to return, in each result row, a distinct `repo` of interest and the collection of users that contributed to it:

```
MATCH (user:User{name:'mattt'})-->(repo)
MATCH (repo)<--(allUsers:User)
RETURN repo, COLLECT(allUsers) AS users;
```

This query assumes that the `CONTRIBUTED` relationships contain no significant properties that need to be returned.

Comment: My query is slightly different, in the sense that I want to have a source (User), target (Repo) list as a result.

The most important part is that I want to have 'mattt's node in the results, and all the users/repos that are 1-2 degrees away.

Comment: OK, see my updated answer. I have also edited the question to include your clarification.

Comment: Is there a simple way to return the actual relations, so that I could rebuild the graph?

Comment: I have removed the `DISTINCT` keyword from within `COLLECT()`, as it is (probably) redundant in this query. A `MATCH` clause will automatically filter out all duplicate relationships.